# C++ do while loop not working

Tags: c++, loops, do-while

I'm trying to make this code work:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

int i;
do
{
    cout << ("please enter a number between 1 and 10");
    cin >> i;

} while(i > 10 && i < 1)
  cout << "the square of the number you have entered is " << i*i;
}
```

Basically, the idea is that a user enters a number between 1 and 10. While the number is not between 1 and 10, it keeps asking the user to enter a number between the values. Then, when the number is between the values, it is squared and returned to the user.

I can't see why this isn't working

Any help is appreciated

Comment: change the condition from "and" to "or".

Comment: Please think a bit more about your code.

Comment: How can `i` be both greater than 10 and less than 1 at the same time ?

Comment: I think you meant this: `while( i > 1 && i < 10 )`

Comment: cheers everyone, the way you put it (high performance mark) makes it make more sense

Comment: Off topic: It won't work for you here, but if you find yourself with a `i < 0` test you can simplify your logic with an `unsigned int`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```
while (i > 10 && i < 1)
```

You want:

```
while (i > 10 || i < 1)
```

Comment: Consider adding a description for OP

Answer (score 0):

You should use an Or `||`, that condition with `&&` will never be true.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (i > 10 && i < 1)
```

Your condition is logically faulty; if reinterpreted, it says:

> *while `i` is greater than 10 **AND** `i` is less than 1*

Judging from your code, the `||` operator should be used:

```
} while (i > 10 || i < 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, your condition is faulty.
a number can't obviously be under 1 AND above 10 at the same time, so the while loop exits immediately after the do statement.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int i;
    do
    {
        cout << ("please enter a number between 1 and 10");
        cin >> i;

    } while (i < 1 || i > 10)

    cout << "the square of the number you have entered is " << i*i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop condition is wrong and will never loop, as `i` cannot be less than 1 `&&` greater than 10 at the same time. You should use the logical OR (`||`) operator instead. In addition, there must be a semicolon placed after the do-while statement. And you probably want and end of line placed after the prompt. Also, you don't want to start the bad habit of polluting the global namespace, even with the awesomeness of `std`. So:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int i;
    do {
        std::cout << "please enter a number between 1 and 10\n";
        std::cin >> i;
    } while (i > 10 || i < 1);

    std::cout << "the square of the number you have entered is " << i*i << std::endl;
}
```